# iPhone location method

Tags: java, iphone, geolocation

I have been wondering how the iPhone determines location based on wifi, because I want to integrate this functionality into a java app of mine.

When I run a location check on my ip, it throws me all the way into some other neighborhood... But when I use my iPhone's location feature, it points right too me. (and GPS is turned off)

How does the iPhone determine location? Because I know it's not using an ip location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses a wifi access point database. See: http://skyhookwireless.com/ and specifically http://www.skyhookwireless.com/press/skyhookapple.php.

Comment: Skyhook is written in C... I need something that can be used in Java

Comment: It is, but it is also how the iPhone determines locations on WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

It's using a triangulation scheme based off of known wifi access points.  When this was first announced, I heard the name [Skyhook Wireless](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/) thrown around, so it's possible that the iPhone is using their databases for location.

Answer (score 0):

Cell tower triangulation? It can see the neighbouring GSM antennas and knows the relative signal strengths. This allows a pretty good estimate